# PL/SQL Create an efficient navigation of records

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need help on the application i'm trying to develop in PL/SQL

Basically my application has 3 screens. 'Parameter screen', 'Results Screen' and 'Details Screen'

Parameter screen - the user will select some parameters from dropdown box within a form. Then they will click
the submit button and will be passed on the next screen (Results screen)

Results screen - an sql query will run taking into account the parameters passed from the previous screen
The result of the query will be displayed in a table sorted by for example (Surname). Example result below

```
|ID|EmployeeID|Surname|Date of Birth|
 1  1234       Adam    11-14-1995
 2  5678       Reyes   06-03-1993
 3  9876       Olivers 03-02-1992
```

The next screen (Details screen) will display more details about the employee. The transition between Results
screen and Details screen will happen by clicking an href link of the employee_surname within the Results screen

So in the above results table, the surname 'Reyes' is a clickable Reyes

After they click a surname from the result, it will call the procedure details_screen (as show in above link) and process
the parameters 'id' and 'emid' to run the query within that procedure and display again more information about that
specific employee. The Details screen would look like this

```
ID: 2
EmployeeID: 5678
Surname: Reyes
First Name: Alan
Date of Birth: 06-03-1993
Hobbies: Basketball
```

I managed to do all the screen from Parameters to Details Screen. However, I want to have some navigation of records
within the 'Details Screen' so they don't have to go back to 'Results Screen' to go through all the records of employees.
I want them to have previous and next navigation within the 'Details screen' such as the following

```
ID: 2
EmployeeID: 5678
Surname: Reyes
First Name: Alan
Date of Birth: 06-03-1993
Hobbies: Basketball

<a href="details_screen?id=1&emid=1234">Previous</a> | <a href="details_screen?id=3&emid=9876">Next</a>
```

That's where i'm stucked with. I don't know how to implement this. 
example. I managed to implement a dirty solution of this but it requires running the same query used
within the Results screen everytime they go forward or backward within the recordset.
My query is more complicated than what I show in this and using my dirty way has a heavy price in terms of performance.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this without running the query over and over again?
Something like do the query once and use the result to render the navigation while the user is still navigating within the 'Details screen'
Then maybe just query again only when the user start from the beginning (The Parameter screen)

I only learned the basic of PL/SQL yesterday and i'm still a noob. I've heard of things like ref_cursor,varrays,nested tables,associative arrays but I don't really understand
them and I don't know if they can even help me with my problem. So please advise on this. Thank you in advance
and sorry for the very long explanation and bad grammar.

Comment: This is usually functionality supplied by the development framework (eg. RoR), rather than by PL/SQL. What are you using?

Comment: hi David, there's no framework. I'm doing it as a part of legacy in house system that uses pure Oracle or PL/SQL. ALthough I can infuse jQuery, javascript and HTML. But that's all I can use as far as I know. :(

Comment: Hmmm, so in what sense does your application have three screens?

Comment: PL/SQL has no U/I, so there must be some front-end or HTML page generation somewhere???  You don't even show us any of the PL/SQL you mention have slow response.

Comment: it's like 3 different web pages (screens) I rendered using PL/SQL and HTML/jQuery using the htp.p() function.

Comment: hi @OldProgrammer sorry i tried to focus the question just on the recordset navigation because the actual query comes from a lot of joins and subqueries. Although that's not the main problem. I'm just asking a way to render navigation without running that query over and over again while the user is on the last page (Details Screen)

Comment: PL/SQL on its own is not a good technology *on its own* for this kind of work. Inevitably you're going to get more and more complex requirements for this UI, and you'll find yourself in a world of pain as you try to reinvent wheels that have been reinvented many times already by others. In your case, I'd recommend looking at something like Oracle Application Express to build your app. It includes session state maintenance and there are sample applications with exactly this kind of functionality built-in.

Comment: @user2447740 Is sort order can be changed on Results screen?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is solvable and pl/sql is a great place to solve it!!!

When in a detail record, you want Next and Previous links.

Here's how to do it:

```
1.  Write 2 pl/sql functions, Previous and Next. 
2.  Each function should take the id the current emp and return a single id'
3.  Then you'll want a variation of:
   a. the pagination query 
 or 
   b. Oracle's lead/lag function
```

The pagination query is best described by Tom:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-jan/o17asktom-093877.html

```
select * 
  from 
( select rownum rnum, a.*
    from (your_query) a
   where rownum <= :M )
where rnum >= :N;
```

The lead/lag query can be found here:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php

Personally, I would use the lead/lag query.

To make it perform, you want to make sure the function returns only the employee id of previous/next employee.

Also, you want an index on surname,employee_id.  Do this so that query only needs to read the index and never needs to reference the table.  In other words, make sure the table is indexed in such a way that the index contains all items being queried.  Use explain plan to review the query's execution plan.  And keep changing the index until you see that the table itself is never referenced.

This effectively turns the query into a b-tree lookup which are super fast.  I use this technique and similar query against millions of rows ---- thousands of time per day.  It's fast.

Next, only call these Prev/Next function when the web user clicks on the link.  Do not call it two times to show the next and prev link.

Doing these things should solve this problem.  And actually, doing this on the database is the best place to do it.  You could solve this in a middle tier by caching the list employees...this is not a good plan because the employees could be added or removed after the list is cached, also the list could be huge.  It's already cached in the database...use it.  Going back to the database is a sure way to always get the correct employee.

Hope this helps.